# Metric screw size for 3.5" HDD

Tags: hard-drive, computer-building, screws

Hey all I am looking to purchase some screws from Amazon for my 3.5" HDDs. Issue being is that the nice ones are all M[x.x] a.k.a. Metric.

I know the size of a HDD screw is 6-32x1/4 but I need to know the equivalent of that in Metric. Only thing I've been able to find is a size of m3.5x0.6.

These are the ones I am thinking about purchasing: [Here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09L4R6B1Q)

So does anyone know what the size it would be?

Comment: Multiply-inch-measure-by 25.4 and you will get the corresponding metric value. *I don't believe there is an exact metric thread equivalent for any choice of inch-based threads.*